# How to transition line graph in d3.js ver4 when triggered by selection from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js, transition

I am trying to make a simple web app/dashboard that displays a simple line graph for a specific school that is selected from a dropdown list. It currently works, *except* when you try to switch back to a school that was already selected. When that happens, the line disappears. I am able to print the data to the console.

More generally, I'm unsure that I'm structuring this the best way. For example, should the update() function really be wrapped in the d3.json() method?

If it matters, my data is being returned by a Django view that sends a JsonResponse with *all* school data (i.e. the data filtering to the specific school happens in d3, not Django. Again, is this the right way of approaching this?)

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%y"); // for dates like "2016-17"

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var projection_line = d3.line()
 .x(function(d) { return x(d.year_short_format); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d.projection); });

// append the svg object to the graph div
var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the json url
var url = "{% url "schoolview:all_schools_enrollments_by_school_and_year" %}";
d3.json(url, function(error, dataInput) {
 if (error) throw error;

 // when a new school is selected, trigger update
 d3.selectAll("#school_select").on("change", update);

 var school_index = document.getElementById('school_select').selectedIndex;
 var selected_school = document.getElementById('school_select')[school_index].value;

 // filter data to the selected school
 data = dataInput.filter(function (d) { return d.school_name == selected_school });

 // format the data
 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year_short_format = parseDate(d.year_short_format);
 });

 // scale the domain of the data
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year_short_format; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.projection; })])

 // append the line path
 svg.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", projection_line)

 // append the x-axis
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

 // append the y-axis
 svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

 function update() {
  var school_index = document.getElementById('school_select').selectedIndex;
  var selected_school = document.getElementById('school_select')[school_index].value;

  // filter data to the selected school
  data = dataInput.filter(function (d) { return d.school_name == selected_school });
  console.log(data);

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.year_short_format = parseDate(d.year_short_format);
  });

  var svg = d3.select("#graph").transition();

  // append the line path
  svg.select(".line")
   .duration(750)
   .attr("d", projection_line(data));

  // append the x-axis
  svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
   .duration(750)
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // append the y-axis
  svg.select(".y.axis") // change the x axis
   .duration(750)
   .call(d3.axisBottom(y));
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so for anyone who is having a similar problem:

In the `update()` function, I was again parsing the date field for each data object. However, this field had already been parsed and overwritten the first time the data was visualized -- the error was from passing an already-parsed field to my `parseDate()` function. Thus the solution: when parsing the data, simply don't overwrite the field.

```
// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.parsed_date = parseDate(d.year_short_format);
});
```

Alternatively, you could parse the data once initially and then don't worry about it again.